# Why am I encountering a foreach undefined error in this .js file running in node.. and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running the following myfile.js on node.
Executing it like so..    node myfile.js

However, it is resulting in a forEach undefined error... I think my syntax is correct too!   Am I missing something?

The error I am getting is ... TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
fs.readdir("/.lib", function(err,files){

    files.forEach(function(fileName) {
        var file = path.join(__dirname, "lib", fileName);
        var stats = fs.statSync(file);

        if (stats.isFile() && fileName !== ".DS_Store"){

            fs.readFile(file,"UTF-8", function(err,contents){
                console.log(contents);
            });

        };
    });

});
```

Comment: You probably want `./lib` as path, or at least `./.lib` The error you're getting means `files` isn't an array. Probably because `readdir` failed.

Comment: Check that `err` parameter

Comment: Check *files*, it's undefined

Comment: Probably need to put an `if(files)` before your file handling block, the callback is firing before you get a result.

Comment: Thanks all..  
So lib is a subfolder, it was an error on my part.. Instead of /.lib, like Chris G mentioned it is ./lib    and that solved it!!  I was pretty sure my syntax was correct too lol.  Thanks much Chris G

Answer (score 1):

Check my example below to see how you can improve your code.
First I checked that the folder is present, then i had to make sure errors are thrown and then an if to see if there are any files.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var searchPath = './lib';

if (fs.existsSync(searchPath)) { // `existsSync` is recommended to be used. `exists` is deprecated

  fs.readdir(searchPath, function(err, files) {

    if (err) {
      // fix error
      throw err;
    }

    if (!files.length) {
      console.log('Empty folder');
    } else {

      files.forEach(function(fileName) {
        var file = path.join(__dirname, "lib", fileName);
        var stats = fs.statSync(file);

        var excludeFiles = ['.DS_Store']

        if (stats.isFile() && excludeFiles.indexOf(fileName) === -1) {

          fs.readFile(file, "UTF-8", function(err, contents) {
            console.log(contents);
          });

        };
      });

    }

  });

} else {
  console.log('Folder doesn\'t exist')
}
```

Comment: Your comment doesn't really make any sense. The reason `exists` is deprecated is to discourage the antipattern of checking the existence of a file or directory before reading from it. The correct pattern is to attempt and then handle the error if it happens to not exist.